# Saved Excel Can't Be opened with Excel 2016

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm using the following code to generate an Excel file

```
private void ExportGridView(GridView gv)
{

    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Factuurtjes.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    // Create a form to contain the grid
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();

    gv.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);

    //Response.Write("Opdrachtgever geselecteerd: " + ddlContractor.SelectedItem.ToString());

    frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
    frm.Controls.Add(gv);
    frm.RenderControl(htw);

    //GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());

    Response.End();
}
```

This all works fine and the excel file gets saved as it should.

I can open the excel file with excel 2013. But when I want to open it with Excel 2016, it gives me a warning message that the file could be damaged.

I would like a solution for this so I can open the files with Excel 2016.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's because exported file is just a html file, not a 'real' xls document. Depending on the office version it can give warnings. Kijk eens naar http://epplus.codeplex.com, veel meer mogelijkheden voor het genereren van Excel documenten

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll proceed in English if you don't mind. On the link you provided are only articles related about excel 2007/2010 files. I need excel 2016 files.

Comment: Also I need to say that the exported file actually is an Excel file since it can be opened with previous versions of Excel.

Comment: The format generated by EPPlus is the Open Office Xml format (xlsx). That is supported by Excel 2016.

Comment: And how would I implement this?

Comment: Take a look at https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2012/create-excel-20072010-spreadsheets-with-c-and-epplus/

Answer (score -1):

I think this [Save-an-Excel-2016-workbook-for-compatibility-with-earlier-versions-of-Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Save-an-Excel-2016-workbook-for-compatibility-with-earlier-versions-of-Excel-169a0336-965b-4430-8554-4e7b5db79947) can help to solve your problem.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for. I'm saving the files via code (provided in the question), not via excel itself.

Comment: in your code excel file extension is .xls which is the versions of Excel prior to 2007 and .xlsx extension is created in the versions of the Excel 2007 and onward, so change yur file name extension Factuurtjes.xls to Factuurtjes.xlsx .

Comment: Ain't working. Already tried that. Still get a warning message.